# Current way of setting language in browsers?

Tags: watir

I've been searching for a while about the recommended and current way of creating Watir::Browser.new for :chrome and set it to accept a certain language. However, this seems to be a topic with little interest, seems to be ever changing, etc.

So, please, can someone explain what the current and recommended way of setting Chrome's language is?

I'm not talking about Chrome's user interface but the Accept-Language HTTP header that later gets sent with the HTTP request so that an application can render it's web UI using the correct locale and language.

For Firefox this works but I have no luck for Chrome:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile["intl.accept_languages"] = "ES"

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(firefox_profile: profile)
caps.platform = "Linux"
caps.version = 20

browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :desired_capabilities => caps
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "intl.accept_languages" is a Chrome preference, so can be passed in as:

```
Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {prefs: {'intl' => {'accept_languages' => 'ES'}}}
```